How do I identify a nucleophile against a base to determine if a reaction proceeds via substitution or elimination?
So our professor taught us, in an attempt to somehow generalize and easily memorize concepts, that substitution reactions involve a nucleophile reagent which attacks the alpha carbon in alkyl halides, while elimination reactions involve a base reagent which attacks the beta carbon in alkyl halides.
My confusion is not whether a reaction would proceed in SN1 or SN2 or between E1 and E2, because there are easy ways to discriminate those choices, such as use of solvent and steric hindrance.
However, my major confusion comes from identifying if the particular reagent would prefer a substitution OR elimination reaction. We've been told that heat favor elimination, but there's not a particular discriminating criteria on how to exactly determine if the reaction would go substitution or elimination.
Based on what my professor said, the differentiating factor is if the reagent is a base or a nucleophile. So now, how do I distinguish both from each other? Both are identified as proton acceptors.

This is a genuine difficulty because many of these reagents are both nucleophiles and bases (e.g alkoxides, primary and secondary amines). You often get both processes occuring in the reaction. The "wrong" process resulting in reduced yields of the desired product..

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/144168/how-to-determine-if-a-base-is-bulky
